# Monte Carlo Simulation- Simulating Sum of a DICE. Matlab CODE.

Tags: probability, matlab, monte-carlo

**Hello everyone**, I try to solve the following problem:

Use Monte Carlo simulation to approximate the sum of the 100 consecutive rolls of a fair die.

**My work in math lab is:**

```
sum=0;
roll= 100; 

for i = 1:roll    
    numbroll = ceil(6*rand);     
    sum=sum+numbroll;
end
sum
```

This code return the sum of 100 rolls.
Back in the book the answer for this exerise said:
[image]

**Question:** I don't know if I missunderstand the statement or not. What is the correct answer? and if someone know how to do the coding for a pair of dice I will be really apreciated.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: From what you have written it really seems like you are supposed to do what you have done. However the book seems to be concerned with finding the distribution of the sums of two dies. It's not hard to change your code to do this.

Comment: To reproduce the book answer make an array to store the results in: `distribution = zeros(12)`. The $i$’th element will count how many times the sum of the two dies are $i$. In the loop throw two dies `dice_one = ceil(6*random)` and `dice_two = ceil(6*random)`. Then sum these up `cursum   = dice_one + dice_two` and increment the array `distribution(cursum) += 1` (I don't know Matlab well so you will have to figure out the correct syntax yourself). Then in the end your array will contain the distribution of the sum of two dies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electro82 was definitely on the right track - just a couple of mods here and this works:

```
sum = 0;
roll = 100; 
distribution = zeros(1,12);

for i = 1:roll    
      dice_one = ceil(6 * rand);  
      dice_two = ceil(6 * rand);
      cursum = dice_one + dice_two;
      distribution(cursum) = distribution(cursum) + 1;
end

distribution/roll
```

Comment: i think it should be `distribution / roll`

Comment: @luke agreed!!!

Answer (score 2):

As far I can do this code, I use Winther advice but need improve.Matlab said it is a problem with the **, part of the code. I hope it helps you a little bit.

```
sum=0;
roll= 100; 
distribution=zeros(12);

for i = 1:roll    
    dice_one = ceil(6*rand);  
    dice_two = ceil(6*rand);
    curmsum= dice_one+ dice_two
    **distribution(cursum)=distribution(cursum)+1**
end

hits(distribution/100)
```